# Does between in Grails criteria include end values

Tags: grails

When using `between` in a Grails criteria, does between include the end values?

i.e. does `between` mean `a < x < b` or `a <= x <= b`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`between` is inclusive

This really isn't a part of Grails or GORM per se, but rather SQL.